# 301 Redirect directly in HTML file with nginx

Tags: html, redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

I wonder if `301 redirect` is possible in an exclusively html static nginx server?

I know that normally it is not possible to make redirect work in html only. In apache server, it is possible to make redirect by using `.htaccess`. I wonder if there is a similar way of doing this in nginx too?

Comment: a redirect in HTML only, if there's absolutely no alternative: `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://domain-you-wish-to-redirect-to.com/">`.

Comment: Thank you! Why did you say "if there's absolutely no alternative"? Is this a bad method?

Comment: It is discouraged, yes -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Drawbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://matthewhelmke.net/2009/01/08/one-url-apache-style-301-redirects-in-nginx/)? I remember testing this quite a while back and it worked for me. Let me know if you are able to get it working or I'll test it on my end